# Merge sort algorithm not working correctly

Tags: c++

As part of a homework assignment, I need to be able to implement a merge sort using a structure as the main argument. Having not been familiar with the merge sort until today, i have attempted to write my own implementation of it. For some reason I cannot get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct MergeArgument
{
    int *numArray;
    int *tempArray;
    int lowIndex, highIndex;
};

void merge(MergeArgument*);
void merge_sort(MergeArgument*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   int SIZE = 25;
    MergeArgument arg;
    int arr[SIZE];
    int temp[SIZE];

    for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
    {
        arr[k] = rand() % 100;
        cout << arr[k] << " ";
    }

    arg.numArray = arr;
    arg.tempArray = temp;
    arg.lowIndex = 0;
    arg.highIndex = SIZE - 1;

    cout << endl;

    merge_sort(&arg);

    cout << "Sorted array: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void merge_sort(MergeArgument *arg)
{   int tempHigh, tempLow;
    if(arg->lowIndex < arg->highIndex)
    {
        tempHigh = arg->highIndex;
        tempLow = arg->lowIndex;
        arg->highIndex = (tempHigh + tempLow) / 2;
        merge_sort(arg);
        arg->highIndex = tempHigh;
        arg->lowIndex = ((tempHigh + tempLow) / 2) + 1;
        merge_sort(arg);
        arg->lowIndex = tempLow;
        merge(arg);
    }

}

void merge(MergeArgument *arg)
{   int low = arg->lowIndex, mid = ((arg->lowIndex + arg->highIndex) / 2), high = arg->highIndex;
    int i = low, lowCounter = low, highCounter = mid + 1;

    while((lowCounter <= mid) && (highCounter <= high))
    {
        if(arg->numArray[lowCounter] < arg->numArray[highCounter])
        {
            arg->tempArray[i] = arg->numArray[lowCounter];
            lowCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            arg->tempArray[i] = arg->numArray[highCounter];
            highCounter++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (lowCounter < mid)
    {
        for (int k = lowCounter; k < mid; k++)
        {
            arg->tempArray[i] = arg->numArray[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int k = highCounter; k <= arg->highIndex; k++)
        {
            arg->tempArray[i] = arg->numArray[k];
            i++;
        }

    }

    for(int k = arg->lowIndex; k <= arg->highIndex; k++)
    {
        arg->numArray[k] = arg->tempArray[k];
    }
}
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
83 86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26 40 26 72 36 11 68 67 29 82    
Sorted array:  
11 -1216235240 15 0 21 26 -1079135248 26 27 -1079135396 29 -1216770650 35 -1216235240 49 -1216492084 59 0 68 72 82 83 0 86 82
```

Can anyone point out what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: No need to copy tags into the title.

Comment: For a C++ program, this looks an awful lot like C to me.

Comment: This is very rough code, I simply want to get the merge sort working before I move on to the big part of the assignment. It will look like C++ by the time I am done with it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you could make it work with only one instance of MergeArgument, and only one argument passed to merge().

Comment: The large negative numbers that you see in your result indicate that you violate the memory bounds of your input array. Check your access to numArray, for example, using assert(...)  -- @Daniel R Hicks: it's depth first an while recursively sorting one branch the other (= the array boundaries) are kept on the stack in the form of local variables.

Comment: If you've written this much code already, it's unlikely you'll go back later to fix it up to make it 'look like C++'. It's the same reason why going back to add comments is unlikely to happen -- it's human nature. The more code you add the great the inertia you have to overcome.

Comment: @michaelnett -- I'm not sure I'm seeing enough local variables.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: You have tempLow and tempHigh to store the array bounds for the subproblem that you put aside while workibg on the other one. Tgat's the same as in the classic way of implement it, isn't it?

Comment: Normally, the `merge()` phase would need to work on two sorted lists; you only seem to provide it with one.  I'm not clear that you need the temp array.

Comment: @MichaelNett -- I'd have to sit down and work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty close to working, although you might want to consider some of the comments folks have made on making this more C++ like.  No doubt this is from hard-won experience that there is never enough time to go back and do what you really should do.

The problem I see is here, in `merge`:

```
if (lowCounter < mid)
{
    for (int k = lowCounter; k < mid; k++)
    {
        arg->tempArray[i] = arg->numArray[k];
        i++;
    }
}
```

You might want to compare and contrast the bounds here to the initial loop.

Comment: Thank you! Although I got it working by redoing my merge function, I am glad to finally see what was wrong with my original implementation.